# Collection view cell is not refreshed inspite of reloaddata

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After reloading collection view, collection view cell changes are not reflected but cellforrow is being called. When we scroll the collection right and then left. The collection view cell is being refreshed. We have debugged the collection view cell, data is configured properly and we are reloading the collection view on the main thread

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Please show your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

use didSet to reload your collection view when your model is modified it'll automatically update.

```
var yourmodel = [yourmodel]() {
        didSet {
            collectionview.reloadData()
        }
    }
```